# details about divergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an unbounded above sequence. Prove that it has a subsequence which diverges to $+\infty$

We have : $\forall k \in \mathbb{R},\exists n \in \mathbb{N};u_n>k$

So let $\phi$ such that $\phi(0)=n_0$ (for $k=0$) and $\phi(n+1)=\inf(p \in \mathbb{N};u_p>\max(u_{\phi(n)},n+1))$

then $u_{\phi(n)}>n$ and $\phi(n+1) \neq \phi(n).$

How can we prove that $\phi(n+1)>\phi(n)?$

Comment: My suggestion, don't. Define $$\phi(n+1)=\inf\{p>\phi(n):u_{p}>\max(u_{\phi(n)},n+1)\}.$$

Comment: @FlorisClaassens why can you define it like this?

Comment: is it because a sequence is bounded above if and only if $\exists l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(u_n)_{n \geq l}$ is bounded?

Comment: If a sequence is unbounded, then the set $X_{k}=\{n:u_{n}>k\}$ is of infinite cardinality. If this was not true, then let $X_{k}$ has a maximum and $$X_{\max X_{k}}=\{n:u_{n}>\max X_{k}\}=\emptyset,$$ which contradicts with the sequence being unbounded.